# Mongoose stream & setInterval leading to memory leaks?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, mongoose, garbage-collection, setinterval

I'm trying to diagnose a memory leak problem in my node application. I'm so confused about GC in V8, and I don't know how to prevent memory leaks in node. I have below code that uses a [mongoose query stream](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream) in a `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var stream = Book
        .find({})
        .stream();

    stream.on('data', function(book) {
        // ...
        book.updated_at = new Date();
        book.save();
        // ...
    });

    stream.on('error', function(err) {

    });

    stream.on('close', function() {

    });
}, 1000);
```

Can the event handlers inside this `setInterval` lead to memory leaks?